# Triggers for Script Lab

Tags: scriptlab

I am switching from google scripts to Script Lab (I have to !). I prefer Google script up to now but I have a lot of scripts on Google script that I will have to replicate on Script Lab. Seems possible.

Oen thing I can not find on Script Lab that will be important is Triggers. I used to run my scripts on Google script every 10 min. Any idea how to trigger automatically by time scrips on Script Lab (in Excel) ?